# Filling values of one table by querying another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables A & B. Both of them have common columns. A has most of those columns empty but B has most of them full.

I want to write a query which will select the columns in A which are not empty & use that to get the other empty columns info from table B & update them in A.

I'm guessing I will be needing select for update here but not sure. need help.

Table A 
Name Address  PhoneNumber
Nick 2nd St NY      null
Dan      null  123-456-7890

Table B 
Name Address  PhoneNumber Sex 
Nick 2nd St NY      987-654-3210 M
 
Dan      5th St NY  123-456-7890  M

result should be that table A fills its empty columns by querying table B. The column SEX doesn't exist in A. A needs just the phone number & address since that's what is empty in A.

Result
Table A
Name Address  PhoneNumber
Nick 2nd St NY      987-654-3210
Dan      5th St NY  123-456-7890

Comment: It may be helpful if you posted a simplified starting data set and a sample desired ending data set to better clarify your question

Comment: You may want to look at the [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function also.  It will choose the first non null value it find.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE
A INNER JOIN B ON A.column = B.column /*the columns that connect the tables*/
SET A.almost_empty_column = B.full_column
WHERE A.almost_empty_column IS NULL OR A.almost_empty_column = '';
```

But I'd suggest, that you have a look at a tutorial at least if not the manual and do not just copy&paste something some guy posts on the internet. You don't learn by not trying to understand what's going on.